# How do I attach a depth buffer to an FBO context using sharpgl

Tags: fbo, depth-testing, sharpgl

So after many headaches trying to get depth testing working with an FBO render context in WPF with SharpGL I understand it's not as simple as setting gl.Enable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) like it is with old-style OpenGL and that I have to attach a depth buffer to the render context.  I'm at a loss for how to achieve this using the WPF/SharpGL pairing that I've built my app around.

All the guides on how to do this start with the creation of the buffers which all happens under the hood so to speak when declaring it as a control in a WPF form.  Is there some way I can reset how it was created or attach a depth buffer after the fact?

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a work-around but it seems like GL version 3.1 has a default depth buffer attached to the FBO while the 3.2 does not.  I was able to get depth testing working by just changing the version back by 0.1.